# exception while Downloading excel file in ASP application

Tags: asp-classic, excel-2003

I am seeking your help for this below problem.
My application is deployed on IIS server which is located in Spain.
While downloading one excel file from my application i am getting an error.

I am getting the following error even i updated Metabase file with ASP buffer size and Asp allowrequest size also:

```
---------------------------
Windows Internet Explorer
---------------------------
Internet Explorer cannot download consultaMatLince.asp from ***** IP address.Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site.  The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.  Please try again later.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check internet setting

got to `tools` >> `internet options` >> `security tab` >> `select Internet option` >> click on `custom Level` >> `Downloads`

`File Download` should be enable.